# Centering an imageview and making it 50% of the width of the screen without constrain lines?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, imageview

I am trying to center an image and make it 50% of the screen width. I tried using a linear layout with weights like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:contentDescription="@string/additionContent"
         app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_additivecolor"
         android:layout_weight="50"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This correctly sets the width and I know how to center it, but the height matches the parent. If I set the height to `wrap_content` the image becomes tiny. `constraintDimensionRatio` did not work either. How can I fix this?

[image]

Image with height being `wrap_content`.

[image]

EDIT

I tried Sudhi's method and this was the result:

[image]

The image is centered, but the size isn't being adjusted by the provided code.
EDIT 2:

I tried Mtak's answer. Here is the result.

[image]

This fills up too much of my screen. So, I removed both views.

[image]

Looks much better but too much space is taken up by the `LinearLayout` because it is `match_parent`. I tried changing this to wrap_content:

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:weightSum="100">
```

And then this happened:

[image]

I have now found many methods for the width to work, but I want the height to be the same size. Most of the time, the height takes up the whole screen, which is not what I want.

Sorry for the confusion. This is what I am looking for:

[image]

As you can see, the height and width of the image are equal. Also, whatever layout contains the image does not stretch all the way to the bottom, but instead wraps the content (which is my main struggle now).

Answer (score 0):

Use fixed height

```
android:layout_height="100dp"
```

Comment: Fixed height would not scale properly on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use Constraint Layouts.
Use the "guidelines" and set the images property "AdjustViewBounds" = true.

Answer (score 0):

I think for alignment you need to use layout gravity and for making the imageview size 50% of the screen you can follow the below code.

```
 final View rootView = findViewById(R.id.llRoot);

    rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            if (rootView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive())
                rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            int width=rootView.getWidth();
            ImageView ivIcon=findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
            ivIcon.getLayoutParams().width=width/2;
            ivIcon.requestLayout();
            // put your code here
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The Xml will look like this

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/square_img" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Result will be

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but the image remains small (not resized).

Comment: Can you make sure that 
int width=rootView.getWidth();
width is getting properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer linear layout with 2 dummy views up and down:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/additionContent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_additivecolor" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this. The views can be removed and it still works. But, now the main linear layout takes up all the space. Setting the height to `wrap_content` minimizes the image.

Comment: The outer layout is there just to make sure that the image is half the height and half the width of it. You can adjust the dimensions of this layout

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to achieve. I see there is a TextView also, so why don't you post the full layout and explain what is the desired result.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. Please check the slightly photoshopped image to see what I am looking for. Let me know if I can make anything clearer. Basically, I want space at the bottom of the page to put more stuff.